# Issue with CAQuietExec CA

Tags: wix, custom-action, wix3.5, wix-iisextension

I'm having an issue with this custom action and I've yet to see a decent example that does something more complex than run a file.

I've read this but it doesn't take into account extra parameters:
http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/qtexec.htm

I just managed to get this to not to complain after seeing something about quoting to receiving this error. I'm not sure why but the command works copying and pasting into a command window.

Anybody have an idea why this won't work in a Quiet CA?

Cheers,
J

```
MSI (s) (E4:F0) [11:04:26:983]: Creating MSIHANDLE (1774) of type 790542 for thread 6896
MSI (s) (E4:28) [11:04:26:983]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL:
C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSI2D95.tmp, Entrypoint: CAQuietExec
MSI (s) (E4!A0) [11:04:26:998]: Creating MSIHANDLE (1775) of type 790541 for thread 9632
MSI (s) (E4!A0) [11:04:26:998]: Creating MSIHANDLE (1776) of type 790531 for thread 9632
MSI (s) (E4!A0) [11:04:26:998]: Closing MSIHANDLE (1776) of type 790531 for thread 9632  
MSI (s) (E4!A0) [11:04:26:998]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting QtExecCmdLine property. Its
current value is '"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -s
W3SVC/1/ROOT/ConfigurationWebService"'.
MSI (s) (E4!A0) [11:04:26:998]: Creating MSIHANDLE (1777) of type 790531 for thread 9632
CAQuietExec:  Error 0x80070003: Command failed to execute.
MSI (s) (E4!A0) [11:04:26:998]: Closing MSIHANDLE (1777) of type 790531 for thread 9632
MSI (s) (E4!A0) [11:04:26:998]: Creating MSIHANDLE (1778) of type 790531 for thread 9632
CAQuietExec:  Error 0x80070003: CAQuietExec Failed
MSI (s) (E4!A0) [11:04:26:998]: Closing MSIHANDLE (1778) of type 790531 for thread 9632
MSI (s) (E4!A0) [11:04:26:998]: Closing MSIHANDLE (1775) of type 790541 for thread 9632
MSI (s) (E4:28) [11:04:26:998]: Closing MSIHANDLE (1774) of type 790542 for thread 6896
Action ended 11:04:26: QtExecExample. Return value 3.
Action ended 11:04:26: INSTALL. Return value 3.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put just the full path to aspnet_regiis into quotes, like this:

```
<CustomAction Id="SetMyAction" Property="MyAction" Value="&quot;[NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR]aspnet_regiis.exe&quot; -s
W3SVC/1/ROOT/ConfigurationWebService"/>
```

where `[NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR]` holds the full path to the folder aspnet_regiis resides in, ending with a back slash. This property is defined in the [WiXNetfxExtension](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wixnetfxextension.htm).

Comment: So that property is teh same value as:

 <Property Id='FXDIR' Value='0'>
            <RegistrySearch Id='FxInstallPathRegistry'
                    Key='SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
                    Name='InstallPath'
                    Root='HKLM'
                    Type='raw'/>
        </Property>

Comment: This property is the full path to the directory where aspnet_regiis is in - the root directory of the .NET Framework 4.0. Don't reinvent the wheel - this property is defined in WiXNetfxExtension I mentioned in my answer

Comment: Somehow the installer gets in an infinite loop, any reason why that would happen?

        <CustomAction Id="AspnetRegIIS" Property="QtExecCmdLine" Value="&quot;[NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR]aspnet_regiis.exe &quot; -s W3SVC/[WEBSITE_ID]/ROOT/[WEBSITE_DIR]" />
        <CustomAction Id="QtExecExample" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="immediate" Return="check"/>

            <Custom Action="AspnetRegIIS" After="InstallFinalize">Not Installed</Custom>
            <Custom Action="QtExecExample" After="AspnetRegIIS">Not Installed</Custom>

Comment: It's not obvious from your sample to me, but I think you don't want it to run immediate, because it somewhat changes the target system... Anyway, make sure that your snippet corresponds to the official docs provided here: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/qtexec.htm

Comment: Unfortunately it does. Logs aren't that helpful but I can say that it loops around the IIS metadata changes then reverts the action then does it again and so on. There is no return value 3 in the log either :(